# How can I add an ampersand (or similar) following all but the final entry in a Matrix loop?

Tags: channel-entries, matrix, pixelandtonic, loop

I have a series of entries coming from a Matrix field on a page. If there is more than one entry I would like a "+" to follow each entry, except for the final entry. I've tried using backspace, but that removes the "+" from all entries.

```
<h2>
{artists}
{if performance_type == "Performance"}
{artist}<a href="{title_permalink="artists/view"}">{title}</a>
{if total_results >= "1"}&nbsp;+&nbsp;{/if}
{/artist}
{/if}
{/artists}
</h2>
```

Any ideas at all would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change this

```
{if total_results >= "1"}&nbsp;+&nbsp;{/if}
```

to this

```
{if count != total_results}&nbsp;+&nbsp;{/if}
```

Then you will get the "+" if there are multiple and it will not put the "+" at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way achieve this is to do by adding `CSS`. For that you just need to create one class `pipe` containing the `+` sign (either with an image or with color). Then put that `pipe` class on respected rows in `Matrix`. This way you can manage it very easily.

```
span.pipe:before {content:" + ";}
span.pipe:first-child:before {display: none;}
```

Comment: That's a great approach, thank you for the input!